# can kube-linter lint only pull requests changes instead whole kubernetes file everytime

Tags: kubernetes

Can I lint only changes or pull requests in the kubernetes file instead of linting whole kubernetes files everytime I make any changes in the kubernetes folder?

I was trying this https://docs.kubelinter.io/#/?id=using-docker

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are referering to the [*kube-linter* GitHub action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/kube-linter), because that's the one [referenced by the kube-linter documentation](https://docs.kubelinter.io/#/?id=kubelinter-github-action).

Yes, that action can be given individual files, the `directory` parameter can be a single file, even though the name doesn't suggest this.

See the [documented parameters](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/kube-linter#parameters):

> | Parameter name | Required? | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `directory` | **(required)** | ***Path of file*** or directory to scan, absolute or relative to the root of the repo. |

(Bold italics emphasis mine).

The parameter is simply given to the `kube-linter` command line; see the [linting step in the `action.yml` definition file](https://github.com/stackrox/kube-linter-action/blob/3e0698d47a525061e50c1380af263c18824c748b/action.yml#L62-L68):

> ```bash
> ./kube-linter $CONFIG lint "${{ inputs.directory }}" --format "${{ inputs.format }}"
> ```

`$CONFIG` is set to `--config <filename>` if you provided a `config` parameter.

In short, it acts *exactly* like [running the tool locally](https://docs.kubelinter.io/#/using-kubelinter?id=running-locally), which explicitly states that it can take either an individual file or a directory:

> - The path to your Kubernetes `yaml` file:
>
>   ```
>   kube-linter lint /path/to/yaml-file.yaml
>   ```
> - The path to a directory containing your Kubernetes `yaml` files:
>
>   ```
>   kube-linter lint /path/to/directory/containing/yaml-files/
>   ```